# hi i have a search code but when i run it it show me error

Tags: php, sql, search

```
<?php  
 include('blog/includes/config.php'); //assuming $db is a database connection, quries can be done 
 using $db->query()

//Post search words
$search = $_GET['search'];

// remove any code from the search term
$search = strip_tags($search);

//No keywords entered.
if ($search == "") {
echo "<p>Opps! You forgot to enter a search term.</p>";
} else {

// perform the search
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog_posts_seo WHERE MATCH(postTitle) AGAINST(':search*' IN 
BOOLEAN MODE), ['search' => $search]");

 echo "<h3>Search Results</h3>";

echo "<p>you searched for <b>$search</b> there are ".count($results)." matches.</p>";

foreach($results as $row) { 
    echo "<h1>$row->postTitle</h1>";
    echo "<p>$row->desc</p>";
} // close while loop

  } // close else
?>

<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input name="search" type="text" size="20" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

when i search in input filed it show me this message:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ['search' => پوست]' at line 1 in /home/takashop/domains/takashop.ir/public_html/search.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/takashop/domains/takashop.ir/public_html/search.php(16): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM b...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/takashop/domains/takashop.ir/public_html/search.php on line 16

Comment: Well it's a good start on prepared statements. Just missing a few statements. Are you using pdo or msqli?

Comment: You need to surround `$search`  with quotes in the query. The string that returns from the value doesn't have it.

Comment: hi thnx i use pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't complied this. There may be some syntax errors.

```
//Post search words
// remove any code from the search term
$search = trim(strip_tags($_GET['search']));

//No keywords entered.
if (empty($search)) {
  echo "<p>Opps! You forgot to enter a search term.</p>";
} else {

// perform the search
$stmt = $db->prepare('
Select
 * 
From
 blog_posts_seo 
Where
 Match(postTitle) AGAINST(:search* IN BOOLEAN MODE);
');
  $stmt->execute(['search' => $search]);
  echo "<h3>Search Results</h3>";

  echo "<p>you searched for <b>$search</b> there are ".$stmt->rowCount()." matches.</p>";

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {  // you don't need the PDO::FETCH_OBJ if it's in your connect statement.
    echo "<h1>$row->postTitle</h1>";
    echo "<p>$row->desc</p>";
  } // close while loop

} // close else
```

Comment: thnx i tested your code and it show error as below:

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN BOOLEAN MODE)' at line 6 in /home/takashop/domains/takashop.ir/public_html/search.php:20 Stack trace: #0 /home/takashop/domains/takashop.ir/public_html/search.php(20): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home/takashop/domains/takashop.ir/public_html/search.php on line 20

Comment: line 20 is:  $stmt->execute(['search' => $search]);

Comment: The error is in the sql. Its just reporting on the execute statement.  I would manually test it in a sql client. The * is odd to me.

Comment: thnx for changing my code it look so better. i hope u can help me after test it.

Comment: Yea,, no problem. I don't do much complex sql. Mostly php.

Comment: i found out problem .your code was all right only need 1 correction replace :search* with :search and it will work well

Comment: thank uo so much Jason K with your help made it easy for me to solve its problem